# jQuery mobile not rendering pages properly

Tags: php, jquery, image, mobile

I am using jQuery mobile and a custom made PHP framework to design a mobile web application. The framework has a layout.phtml file in templates which defines the basic layout of the view this contains:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="layout">
        <div data-role="header">.....</div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <?= $menu_bar ?>
            <img src="images/system/logo.gif">
            <?= $body ?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Then every controller has dedicated one or more views which contains the mark-up. But the problem I am facing is when I click any link in the home page, it opens the second page, but the image paths on the second page appends to that on the first page. For e.g:
if I load a first page everything is fine and the url of the page is "localhost/project/login". When, the second page opens, the image source on the second page changes to "localhost/project/loginimages/system/logo.gif". When I refresh the page manually it goes back to normal i.e "images/system/logo.gif". Why does this happens?

Another thing that happens, when I login or logout the name of the controller remains in the URL. However, actually the login and logout functions goes to a certain controller and then redirects the user to the dedicated page. But with jQuery mobile redirection doesn't seem to be working.
I tried searching on internet, but couldn't find any help.

Hope I have explained myself.

Comment: have you tried an absolute link?

Comment: yup. That doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

due  the image source on the second page changes to `"localhost/project/loginimages/system/logo.gif"` that's mean yo have no absolute link, or you can try load the page whit out ajax, try to add `data-ajax="false"` to the link property

Comment: OK this works for the links, but enabling this, takes the page transition effect away.
And on the logout link, the redirection is still not working. The pages goes to the controller and removes all the cookies and usets the sessions but header('Location: $url'); still doesn't works.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: try to add `data-transition="fade"` see if that work, i don't understand about redirecting not working, i guest if you using php instead it will be easy to manage redirecting, for some aditional reason, am not using `header('Location')` when using Jquery Mobile, using javascript to redirecting more reliable i though

Comment: and how can I include an absolute link, because its a PHP framework and only public directory is accessible, which lies in /var/www/project/core/public etc. I cannot use img src="/var/www/project/core/public/images" or can I?

Comment: I have tried it earlier but it doesn't work; "data-transition" = "fade". It also says in the documentation of JQuery mobile that the transition effects will not work if the data-ajax is false or rel=external is enabled. Because these are forcing the framework to reload the entire page. But I am struggling to understand how can achieve it in MVC structure. All the views are in templates directory and Images in public/images directory.
:(
Any ideas?

Comment: Its a custom build PHP framework for my company. Its based on MVC architecture.

Comment: if you using php framework, it must be have a base_url like Codeigniter, tyr to find base_url of your app, for find absolute path for image you could be use php function to find the hostname for absolute link, use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` and add some path for additional path

Comment: yeah base url is defined in the config file. So are you saying in theimg src=$base_url."/images/logo.gif"

Comment: ok this is the Homepage "http://mywebsite.com/mobile"
the image source is src="<?= URL_ROOT ?>/core/public/images/system/logo.gif"
when i click on a link "http://mywebsite.com/mobile/users/test"
the img src becomes src="http://mywebsite.com/mobile/users/testcore/public/images/system/logo.gif"